# PCB Board disappeared in Altium after redefine shape

Tags: pcb, altium

I tried to change my board size and potentially misclicked as I was redrawing the board. Is there a way to get the board back?

I redefined the shape again and it shows up in 2D view but is missing in 3D view as you can see in the 2nd picture linked. (Undo did nothing to bring the board back)

[image: PCB before redefining shape]

[image: PCB after redefining shape]

Comment: What happens when you type <shift> S  once or twice?

Comment: The designator names change color and that's it.

Comment: I just went back to a previous save, couldn't figure out what had happened.

Comment: What version of Altium ?

Comment: @citizen 20.2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me I had to go to board view using the 1 key, and the go to the properties of the board and rename the board region. In my case, I changed the name from "Layer Stack Region 1" to "Layer Stack Region".

Comment: Yes!  Why on earth did that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is if you have auto save turned on you can go back in the folder where your project is located and there should be a history folder open it and there is some zip files. These contain the PCB files and you can recover to the last time the file was saved. Also make sure you have auto save turned on, it can save you a lot of time the files get corrupted or if you make changes and can't roll back

Answer (score 0):

Lost half an hour for that.
As i defined the "board shape from selected objects" in "Desgin->Board Shape", I accidentally also selected the shape of a component and my board got the size of the selected component. I selected only the shape of the board I wanted, defined the shape of the board again and it worked. Pay attention that no other component shares the layer you draw the shape of your board.